# How to validate openlayers map bounding box

Tags: wms, openlayers-5

I have couple of sub layers in WMS service. All of them have EX_GeographicBoundingBox with same format like:

```
0: 100
1: -50.0243292
2: 180.05332479999998
3: 0.0089988
```

except one layer has format like:

```
0: 12245143.9872601
1: -5621521.48619207
2: 17254521.0729574
3: -1118889.97485796
```

since my code using this following code to convert bounding box into ol coordinator:

```
ol.proj.transformExtent(extent, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
```

so the last layer causing crashing the application.

How to validate this following format before convert into ol coordinator:

```
0: 12245143.9872601
1: -5621521.48619207
2: 17254521.0729574
3: -1118889.97485796
```